# Apache Camel Spring Javaconfig Unit Test No consumers available on endpoint

Tags: spring, unit-testing, apache-camel

I have the following route configuration:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:in").to("direct:out");
    }
}
```

When I try to test it:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyRouteTest.TestConfig.class }, loader = CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader.class)
@MockEndpoints
public class MyRouteTest {
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:out")
    private MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:in")
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfig extends SingleRouteCamelConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Override
        public RouteBuilder route() {
            return new MyRoute();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testRoute() throws Exception {
        mockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("Test Message");

        producerTemplate.sendBody("Test Message");

        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

> org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException:
>   No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://out].
>   Exchange[Message: Test Message]

It looks like the Mock is not picking up the message from the endpoint.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that mock endpoints just intercept the message before delegating to the **actual** endpoint. Quoted from [the docs](http://camel.apache.org/mock):

> Important: The endpoints are still in action. What happens differently
>   is that a Mock endpoint is injected and receives the message first and
>   then delegates the message to the target endpoint. You can view this
>   as a kind of intercept and delegate or endpoint listener.

The solution to your problem is to tell certain endpoints (the ones that expect a consumer in your case) *not* to delegate to the actual endpoint. This can easily be done using `@MockEndpointsAndSkip` instead of `@MockEndpoints`:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyRouteTest.TestConfig.class }, loader = CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader.class)
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("direct:out") // <-- turns unit test from red to green ;)
public class MyRouteTest {
// ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue because, in your route configuration, there is no route with "direct:out" consumer endpoint.

add a line like some thing below,

```
from("direct:out").("Anything you want to log");
```

So that direct:out will consume the exchange and In your test, mock will be able check the received text without any issues. Hope this helps !!

Comment: What do you mean with there is no route with "direct:out"? I do register a mock endpoint ("mock:direct:out") to consume the message. Although your purposed solution will work I don't think the implementation should change to satisfy this test?

Comment: You are registering the mock only after your camel context is started. If you want your mock to register properly, you have to use advisewith. Pl refer the the sample here "http://camel.apache.org/mock.html".

Comment: I found some example with @MockEndpoints that should be enough. How should I change the code with advisewith preferably using the annotation variant?

Comment: While this works, it's a rather unnecessary workaround as the delegation to the actual endpoint can be skipped by using a different Mock annotation on class level (see my answer for details)